# Solr 5.1.0 dataimporthandler directory is empty

Tags: php, mysql, lucene, dataimporthandler, solr5

I was trying to integrate Solr 5.1.0 to mysql and as given in the tutorial (http://lasithtechavenue.blogspot.in/2013/11/crawling-mysql-database-with-apache-solr.html), everything is set upto

```
<lib dir="../../../contrib/dataimporthandler/lib" regex=".*\.jar" />
<lib dir="../../../dist/" regex="solr-dataimporthandler-\d.*\.jar" />
<lib dir="../../../dist/" regex="mysql-connector-java-\d.*\.jar" />
```

But when go to the url http://localhost:8983/solr/#/ the following error is generated.

```
SolrCore Initialization Failures
new_core: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error loading class 'org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler'
```

When i checked the `contrib/dataimporthandler` there is not a folder like `lib`.

Can someone help me to solve this ?

Thanks in advance,
Tismon Varghese

Answer (score 1):

In Solr 5.x the director path has became dynamic.

replace you path code with,

```
<lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/dist/" regex="solr-dataimporthandler-.*\.jar" />
<lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/dist/" regex="mysql-connector-java-.*\.jar" />
```

These may help you.

If you running your solr in Cloud mode then, After changing please upload to zookeeper & restart your solr instance.

Thanks

Comment: This solved my same problem. Thank you! Was looking for an hour on google.

Answer (score 1):

Edit your **solrconfig.xml** and add the path to the library as below

```
<lib dir="../../../../dist/" regex="solr-dataimporthandler-.*\.jar" />
```

and the jar is available at path `sol-5.1.0/dist`

named `solr-dataimporthandler-5.1.0.jar`

and not at the path solr-5.1.0/contrib/dataimporthandler